# Is this expression positive or negative given the assumptions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-test

Consider:

```
Expre78 = ( b βa (μ (-1 + ν) - ξ) + μ (μ + ξ + ρ) (γa + μ + σ))/(μ (μ + ξ + ρ) σ);

Assuming[
   {b > 0, βa > 0, μ > 0, 0 < ν < 1, βi > 0, ξ > 0, ρ > 0, γa > 0, σ > 0}, 
   Reduce[$Assumptions \[Implies] Expre78 >= 0, {}, Reals]
]
```

**Is this expression positive or negative given the assumptions?**

***Edit:***

if `r0<1` then i want to check whether `Expre78 <0`

```
r0=(b (\[Mu] - \[Mu] \[Nu] + \[Xi]) (\[Beta]a (\[Alpha] + \[Gamma]i + \
    \[Eta] + \[Mu]) + \[Beta]i \[Sigma]))/(\[Mu] (\[Alpha] + \[Gamma]i + \
    \[Eta] + \[Mu]) (\[Mu] + \[Xi] + \[Rho]) (\[Gamma]a + \[Mu] + \
    \[Sigma]));

        Expre78 = (b \[Beta]a (\[Mu] (-1 + \[Nu]) - \[Xi]) + \[Mu] (\[Mu] + \
\[Xi] + \[Rho]) (\[Gamma]a + \[Mu] + \[Sigma]))/(\[Mu] (\[Mu] + \[Xi] \
+ \[Rho]) \[Sigma]);

Assuming[{b > 0, \[Beta]a > 0, \[Beta]i > 0, \[Mu] > 0, 
  0 < \[Nu] < 1, \[Gamma]a > 0, \[Gamma]i > 0, \[Xi] > 0, \[Rho] > 
   0, \[Eta] > 0, \[Alpha] > 0, \[Sigma] > 0, r0 < 1}, 
 Reduce[$Assumptions \[Implies] Expre78 <= 0, {}, Reals]]
```

Comment: Did you try `FindInstance[{Expre78 < 0 && b > 0 && \[Beta]a > 0 && \[Mu] > 0 && 
   0 < \[Nu] < 1 && \[Xi] > 0, \[Rho] > 0, \[Gamma]a > 0, \[Sigma] > 
   0}, {b, \[Beta]a, \[Mu], \[Nu], \[Xi], \[Rho], \[Gamma]a, \
\[Sigma]}]`?

Comment: @user293787 I amended the assumptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Expre78 = (b βa (μ (-1 + ν) - ξ) + μ (μ + ξ + ρ) (γa + μ + σ))/
   (μ (μ + ξ + ρ) σ);
```

It can be either.

To be nonnegative

```
Assuming[{b > 0, βa > 0, μ > 0, 
  0 < ν <= 1, ξ > 0, ρ > 0, γa > 0, σ > 0}, 
 Reduce[Expre78 >= 0] // Simplify]

(* b βa (μ - μ ν + ξ) <= μ (μ + ξ + ρ) (\
γa + μ + σ) *)

vars = Variables[Level[Expre78, {-1}]];
```

Nonnegative values

```
Expre78 >= 0 /. 
 FindInstance[{Expre78 >= 0, b > 0, βa > 0, μ > 0, 
   0 < ν <= 1, ξ > 0, ρ > 0, γa > 0, σ > 0}, vars, 5]

(* {True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Negative values

```
Expre78 < 0 /. 
 FindInstance[{Expre78 < 0, b > 0, βa > 0, μ > 0, 
   0 < ν <= 1, ξ > 0, ρ > 0, γa > 0, σ > 0}, vars, 5]

(* {True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

**EDIT:** For the revised question

```
Clear["Global`*"]

r0 = (b (μ - μ ν + ξ) (βa (α + γi + η + μ) + βi σ))/
  (μ (α + γi + η + μ) (μ + ξ + ρ) (γa + μ + σ));

Expre78 = (b βa (μ (-1 + ν) - ξ) + μ (μ + ξ + ρ) * 
  (γa + μ + σ))/(μ (μ + ξ + ρ) σ);

vars = Variables[Level[Expre78 && r0, {-1}]]

{b, α, βa, βi, γa, γi, η, μ, ν, ξ, ρ, σ}
```

There are no nonpositive cases

```
FindInstance[{Expre78 <= 0, b > 0, βa > 0, βi > 0, μ > 0, 
  0 < ν < 1, γa > 0, γi > 0, ξ > 0, ρ > 0, η >
    0, α > 0, σ > 0, r0 < 1}, vars]

(* {} *)
```

or

```
Reduce[{Expre78 <= 0, b > 0, βa > 0, βi > 0, μ > 0, 
  0 < ν < 1, γa > 0, γi > 0, ξ > 0, ρ > 0, η >
    0, α > 0, σ > 0, r0 < 1}]

(* False *)
```

There is at least one positive case

```
inst = FindInstance[{Expre78 > 0, 
   b > 0, βa > 0, βi > 0, μ > 0, 
   0 < ν < 1, γa > 0, γi > 0, ξ > 0, ρ > 0,
   η > 0, α > 0, σ > 0, r0 < 1}, vars]

(* {{b -> 7/2, α -> 1, βa -> 1, βi -> 3/2, γa -> 1,
   γi -> 1, η -> 1, μ -> 1, ν -> 1/2, ξ -> 1,
   ρ -> 1, σ -> 1}} *)

Expre78 /. inst[[1]]

5/4
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you attach examples showing where it is positive and negative?

Comment: @Math please make an effort to understand the answer by BobHanlon, the examples are created there by using `FindInstance`.

Comment: Look at the `FindInstance` expressions shown prior to evaluating the `ReplaceAll`

Comment: @BobHanlon, I have added an addendum since I missed on important assumption.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you for the update. I have one question; if `Reduce[{Expre78 > 0, b > 0, βa > 0, βi > 0, μ > 0, 
  0 < ν < 1, γa > 0, γi > 0, ξ > 0, ρ > 0, η >
    0, α > 0, σ > 0, r0 < 1}]` outputs `false` then why when I change the reduce statement to `Expre78 > 0` (or even `Expre78 >= 0`) it shows conditions? Shouldn't it output `true`?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't conclude that the negation is True. Presumably, it goes through a different sequence of transformations and hits some roadblock and times out.

Comment: @BobHanlon So just to conclude, with the assumptions, `Expre78` is always positive and/or non-negative?

Comment: From what Mathematica provided, I conclude that there are only positive values (perhaps only one).